# Remove comma separated string from another comma separated column value in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

In my table, email recipients list is stored as a single column comma separated value. And I have another table with email addresses to be blocked as a single column value.
Now I want to remove blocked emails from the first table and update only allowed emails in the first table column value.

I already have function to return comma separated table value. 
Is there any default function or easiest way to achieve this?

EX:

```
Select EmailAddress From TableA
'abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com,ghi@gmail.com,jkl@gmail.com,mno@gmail.com'

Select EmailAddress From TableB
'abc@gmail,mno@gmail'
```

Expected result after update:

```
Select EmailAddress From TableA
'def@gmail.com,ghi@gmail.com,jkl@gmail.com'
```

Comment: You can do this by converting the whole thing to XML, splitting, `EXCEPT`ing, then using XML again to concatenate stuff -- but you *really don't want to*. You *want* to have the email addresses stored into separate rows. You say you "have [a] function to return [a] comma separate table value" -- is that operating on rows, by any chance?

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: why is `TableB` comma delimited as well? it would make more sense for a row for each blocked email address

Comment: @WhatsThePoint - Can I make it simple, if TableB has row for each bloked email address.

Comment: @Ask_SO that doesn't answer my question